# OpenCL, float vs uint, expected performance gain?

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, opencl

What would be the expected performance gain with using *(u)int16* over *float* in an OpenCL kernel ? If any ?
I expect the memory transfer to be roughly divided by two but what of the device load ?

Strangely I can hardly find any benchs or documentations on the subject. (or maybe my google fu is just failing me...)

I'm working on image processing (filtering mostly). The precision is not that critical, indeed the result of several kernels operations is cast into a char. We narrowed several operations where using shorter data types is acceptable. So I was wondering if those operations can be speed up by using shorter data where the precision is not critical.

thanks for your help.

Comment: OpenCL is too platform agnostic to meaningfully answer this. On what kind of accelerator is this kernel running? GPU-ish or CPU-ish?

Comment: at the moment, both CPU and GPU, but we are targeting entry-level professional GPU (eg: ati firepro scale).

Comment: You have to measure on the relevant hardware. There is no way to tell what magic the {C,G}PU and compiler performs on your source code, and thus impossible to say. Note that at least sometimes, code size will also make a difference to the result, so if, for example, float instructions are longer, although theoretically as fast, then that may lose you valuable performance from code-growth.

Comment: It also depends on whether your code is calculation or memory bound.

Comment: thx for your answers, the code is more calculation bound (several successive convolutions, gaussians and thresholds)

Comment: Well, on a typical GPU (the ones that ATI and NVIDIA write their programming guides for), float operations have the best possible throughput. Integer operations are usually equal but 32 bit multiplies have at best half the throughput (there are 24 bit multiply instructions though). The new-ish "scalar" architectures don't seem to support stuffing several 16 bit operations into one vectorized instruction either. In short, it seems like there's nothing to gain aside from memory/BW. This is my general impression from reading lots, obviously you still need to benchmark.

Comment: @delnan ok thx, i just did a little test on a simple convolution, indeed float is faster than int16 (~20%) and bw usage is divided by ~1.9. So I guess i'll stick to float

Comment: Modern hardware is as fast with float as with int, sometimes faster. Is half-float (16 bit float) enough precision for your task? It has the bandwidth of 16u but is float (much less precision and range compared to full float of course).

Comment: @Dithermaster precision would be largely sufficient, yet bw usage is not the main issue atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPUs tend to do floating-point operations better than integral. For example, some will have extra pipelines for floating-point ops, and making everything integral just reduces the GPU's throughput.  Data copy may not be your bottleneck and halving the amount by using 16-bit integers may not help.  Moreover, on integrated GPU's like Intel or AMD's you can get zero-copy behavior.  So the effect on image or buffer size is minimal (to a point).

Also, you might look into 16-bit floating point number support.  That gets you the best part of both worlds (half the data w/ floating point numbers).